# Alamofire Swift-2.0 branch fails with Errors

Tags: swift2, alamofire, ios9

I have Xcode7-beta4 and I added the swift2.0 branch in podfile

`pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'`

But my build fails with the following errors

[image]

Any Idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode beta 5 is available,

I have no issue with the beta 5 and alamofire branch "Swift-2.0"
you can download it right there :

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/